# R how to get same sample size from different categorical values

Tags: r, cross-validation, sample, kruskal-wallis-test

I have an unbalanced set of records for different values of a categorical variable as shown below:

```
user_choice     freq
1   4           3711
2   5          17794
3   6          54600
4   7         228148
5   8          77473
6  NA            181
```

I'd like to pull the same number of sample rows from each value which seems to be helpful for performing the kruskalmc.

Which package could I use to pull an equal number of rows for each value? And I'd like to have a training and test set as well.

So the desired outcome I think I want for the training set would be:

user_choice     freq
1   4           2000
2   5           2000
3   6           2000
4   7           2000
5   8           2000

And a similar number of records for the test set, just as an example:

user_choice     freq
1   4           1000
2   5           1000
3   6           1000
4   7           1000
5   8           1000

I looked at the sample set and the sampling set but didn't see how to obtain the above results.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is about statistics - it's about creating validation sets (train vs. test sets) to validate results. It is a necessary step for machine learning. I am appreciate of the help I got from @undergradstudent as I am now able to perform the Kruskal-Wallis test, which, of course is a statistical test. Would this be off-topic? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataf <- data.frame(a = sample(1:5,100000, replace= T), b = rnorm(100000))


undersample <- function( data_name, column_name, train_n = 3000, test_n = 1000){

testdata <- data.frame()
traindata <- data.frame()

listp <- unique(dataf[column_name])
for(i in listp){

indices <- sample(which(data_name[column_name]==i), train_n + test_n)

trainindex <- sample(indices, train_n)
testindex <- setdiff(indices, trainindex)

traindata <- rbind(data_name[trainindex,])
testdata <- rbind(data_name[testindex,])

}
newList <- list("test" = testdata, "train" = traindata)

}

undersampledata <- undersample(data_name = dataf, column_name ="a" )

head(undersampledata$test)
head(undersampledata$train)
```

Make sure you remove the NA, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I ran into an error with this line: undersampledata <- undersample(data_name = mysampledata, column_name = a). Error was:  Error in `[.data.frame`(mysampledata, column_name) : object 'a' not found . What is column_name = a?  Thanks

Comment: I had a typo. The column named should be passed as a string with quotations. So undersampledata <- undersample(data_name = nameofthedataframe, column_name = "user_choice") I used  undersampledata <- undersample(data_name = mysampledata, column_name = "a") on the data set I generated to show it works. For you it would be something different.

Comment: Thanks, and I also think that this line: testdata <- rbind(data_name[trainindex,])
should be changed to this: 
traindata <- rbind(data_name[trainindex,]). One final question - I see that it is a list, what I would like are two data frames, one for each set.  Please let me know if you can help me with that. Otherwise, it looks good as I have two lists with the specified number of observations.

Comment: It should be traindata. You can convert them to datafame using df <- as.data.frame.list(undersampledata$test)